# Prevent google geocoder API from returning status 'OK' when only single, double or rand chars are used

Tags: javascript, google-places-api, angular7, google-geocoding-api

If I pass in just a 'S' to the geocode api I get a result back with status of "OK". Is there any way to just get a status back of 'OK' when a City or Town is entered? So that I don't get false results when a user enters in stuff like

ex. 'S' or 'SA' or 'TTT'

```js
this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
this.geocoder.geocode({
    address: this.registerForm.get('city').value,
    componentRestrictions: {
      country: 'US'
    }
  },
  (results, status) => {
    // do stuff here.
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Geocoding API is not an address validation service. It was never designed for this purpose. The main idea of Geocoding API is providing best match for your input text according to certain criteria. So, it will always try return a result even if input text doesn't have much sense. Unfortunately, there is no way to change this behavior of service.

If you would like your users to send only valid addresses, have a look at autocomplete service (type-ahead-search behavior). This way users will select one of suggested addresses and you can get detailed information for selected place ID (which exists in Google database).

For further details look at the autocomplete documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Xomena. Yes I'm also using autocomplete and restricting by cities/towns. But I need a way to find a (lat, lng) if the user **DOESN'T** select from the autocomplete dropdown. And just tabs down or enters data and clicks on another field. So I use geocoding to search their input for a (lat, lng). This is for a dating site on the user registration form, where I try to collect location data. The user selects a country then types in a location by city/town.

Comment: So if the user selects "United States" then types in "South Dakota" in the city/town input and then tabs down, I need to search on that but I don't want to fetch a result that is that broad (state)! S I need to be able to somewhow check if its broader than a city/town? And then show an error that tells them to try another search that is for a city/town.